# Nodejs Express serve same variable page without using url parameters

Tags: node.js, express, url

I am trying to serve a single page using node js. I want the page to be different depending on a value the user passes in. I know how to do this using url parameters like: `site.com/page?var=value` but I want my url's to look like this instead: `site.com/value`. Right now all I'm doing is serving the page.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../template/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the doc : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Why don't you use urlParameters ?

```
app.get('/:pageValue', function (req, res) {
    const value = this.req.params.pageValue;  // <---- THIS is your value

    ___ your next code ___
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../template/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't like the way the parameters look, I want a typical user to be able to read the page urls.